# How to make below dotted line path using css

Tags: css

I'd like to build something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCsNX.png

I am able to make This:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCDD1.png

Please help in making the rounded edges look better and it matches my above requirement.

Below is the html i used:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 c-col" ng-repeat="n in c.testD">
    <div class="c-d">
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the CSS i used:

```
.c-row{
    height: 32.5rem;
    background-color: #EEF1FF;
    .c-col{
        height: 32.5rem;
        background-color: #EEF1FF;
        .c-d{
            margin: auto;
           
        }
        &:nth-of-type(odd) {
            border-top:  5px dashed #49A252;
            border-top-left-radius: 4.5rem;
            border-top-right-radius: 4.5rem;

            :before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                right: 0px;
                top: 3.5rem;
                height: 0.1rem;
                height: calc(100% - 7.6rem);
                border-right:  5px dashed #49A252;
              }
          }
          &:first-child{
                border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;
          }
          &:nth-of-type(even) { 
            border-bottom: 5px dashed #49A252;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 4.5rem;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 4.5rem;
            :before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                right: 0px;
                bottom: 3.4rem;
                height: 0.1rem;
                height: calc(100% - 7rem);
                border-right:  5px dashed #49A252;
              }
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would "cut" the squares half vertically and rotate every second 180 deg:

```css
.container > div {
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
            border: 4px dashed red;
            border-bottom-color: transparent;           
            margin-left: -4px;
            float: left;            
        }

        .container > div:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
            transform: rotate(180deg);
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Complex Drawing, I will recommend you to use SVG
Sample output for your requirement is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="500" width="500">
  <path d="m 5 0 l 80 0 a 20 20 0 0 1 20 20 l 0 80 a 20 20 0 0 0 20 20 l 80 0 a 20 20 0 0 0 20 -20 l 0 -80 a 20 20 0 0 1 20 -20 l 80 0 a 20 20 0 0 1 20 20 l 0 80 a 20 20 0 0 0 20 20 l 80 0 a 20 20 0 0 0 20 -20 l 0 -80 a 20 20 0 0 1 20 -20 l 80 0" stroke="green" stroke-dasharray="5,5" stroke-width="2" fill="none" /> 
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: we need to put 4 div under these dotted lines. i am not sure if we can add div under svg. Any idea how to add div tag under this svg path.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for you done with your exact requirement

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <p>Text before SVG. I'm some boring text. Such incredibly boring text. Who would possibly want to read such boring text?</p>
    <svg width="600" height="600">
        <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" stroke="green" stroke-width=".9" fill="blue" 
  style="fill-opacity: 0.2; stroke-opacity: 1" />
  <rect x="150" y="150" rx="5" ry="5" width="350" height="150" stroke-width="0.5"
  style="fill: blue; stroke: red; fill-opacity: 0.2; stroke-opacity: 1" />
    </svg>
</div>
<div>
    <svg width="600" height="600">
        <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" stroke="green" stroke-width=".9" fill="blue" 
  style="fill-opacity: 0.2; stroke-opacity: 1" />
  <rect x="150" y="150" rx="5" ry="5" width="350" height="150" stroke-width="0.5"
  style="fill: blue; stroke: red; fill-opacity: 0.2; stroke-opacity: 1" />
    </svg>
    <p>SVG before text. I'm some boring text. Such incredibly boring text. Who would possibly want to read such boring text?</p>
    <svg height="500" width="500">
        <path d="m 5 0 l 80 0 a 20 20 0 0 1 20 20 l 0 80 a 20 20 0 0 0 20 20 l 80 0 a 20 20 0 0 0 20 -20 l 0 -80 a 20 20 0 0 1 20 -20 l 80 0 a 20 20 0 0 1 20 20 l 0 80 a 20 20 0 0 0 20 20 l 80 0 a 20 20 0 0 0 20 -20 l 0 -80 a 20 20 0 0 1 20 -20 l 80 0" stroke="green" stroke-dasharray="5,5" stroke-width="2" fill="none" /> 
        Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
      </svg>
</div>
<style>
    p {
    width: 200px;
    z-index:10;
}
div {
    position: relative;
}
svg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```